# how to include DIRS and LIBRARIES while compiling a files that requires python3?

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, cmake-gui

I am trying install a software by Cmake, in its Makefile.config file has two lines for including the python 3 libraries like

```
# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
# PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
#                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
```

How can I export these lines while I am making it?
for the first line of `PYTHON_INCLUDE` I only knew that

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.5/
```

what about other lines?

Comment: If you build a software with CMake, the file `Makefile.config` has no sense for your: this file is for direct building with `make`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that is why I am asking here, I do not have those files and only have cmakelist.txt. I want to know what is the proper way of including this paths while I am compiling with cmake? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `CMakeLists.txt` use:

```
find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(<your-target> ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Searching for python uses standard CMake module [FindPythonLibs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindPythonLibs.html).

---

In case of CMake error while searching the Python, try to google - there are several question on Stack Overflow about that.